# Prettier: Remove additional spaces before self-closing tag />

Tags: html, format, prettier

We want to **enforce** removal of any additional spaces  `/>` before self-closing tags in our HTML using prettier. Judging by [the options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), we can't find any relevant options to disable this behaviour.

[Live example](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAllADgVxgAhgE8s4BeAHRHgA8Yr90ATSkLAJwgDN0AbOALRQAhgFs4DdnACOOdFKYB6AHwgANCAhYY6aAGdkoYe04B3AArGEBlMN6nhRAxoBG7YWADWcGAGUxcAAymHDIXHZ6cK7uXj6+WB6YAObIMOw4USBwoi5wTEx5gcJQSTjCSXAAYhDsosIwOiXIIMJ4EOogABYworwA6p3o8HoJYHC+1kPoAG5DRM1ges4gmJHsMObuSXVhEZkAVno0vsn8AIo4EPC7vJEaCexrzd29HRyYMH3MMJ3IABwABnunEifXcWGaHDga2moQ0siucE2WhsLT0QjgeTyHSksnkSK2OyQ4VumUionQqXSZNOcAuiJud2owhcXyYP2QACYNGlhHxkgBhCCiIlZPQAVg6OEiABUWTYSUzphkAJJQAqwXxgdjobQAQXVvmI-EZcAAvmagA).

How can we enforce **no additional spaces** before self-closing tags: `/>` using prettier?

Comment: There is no such option in Prettier and they are not going to add it because prettier is "opinionated" - see https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

Comment: Like szx. There is no such option but you can create a simple batch command for that of a js script